# Getting the full address of an interface item

Tags: python

In blender menus, I can CTRL+C on a menu item and get it's full address (correct me if this is the wrong terminology) that is ready to paste in python code. In a properties window, there are some buttons that I can right click on and choose "Copy Python Command." However, if I right click on the X field in the Transform Location in the same Properties window, I only have the option "Copy Data Path" which puts the text "location" in the clipboard. If I hover over the same X field, I see at the bottom of the tool tip:

```
bpy.data.objects["Plane"].location[0]
```

Is there any way to copy this to the clipboard?

Here's why I'm doing this: I have an idea on how to simplify the workflow for Drivers to somewhat mimic similar functionality in the best compositor in the history of VFX; Shake (R.I.P.) and want to make a proof of concept for how this will work. Basically copying an address to a value number field and pasting that in another number field with the option of using it as part of an expression. The expression would be parsed and then executed via

```
exec()
```

and

```
eval()
```

commands.

So basically enabling expressions in a number field and allowing that expression to include updated values from object parameters.

I think that this would be a great addition to blender, but noone seems to be interested in the idea. But if I could *show* everyone what a great idea it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of keyboard shortcuts you can use to copy different forms of fields and components out of the interface.

The simplest is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - this copies the *value* of the field (eg, `0.0`).

The next is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - this copies the *local path* to that value (eg, `location`).

Finally, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - this copies the *absolute path* to that value (eg, `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[0]`).

Comment: And there it is. I thought I'd tried every key combination of CTRL SHIFT ALT & C, but I guess I missed the big one.

Comment: It looks like Absolute Path was the terminology I was looking for. Thanks for the help, Rich.